# Put hash values into array RUBY

Tags: ruby, api, hash

I am using ruby 1.9.3 and am receiving the following hash back from an API GET request:

```
puts api_response

{"id"=>"5172901-01", "firstName"=>"a", "lastName"=>"b", "email"=>"test@test.com", "gender"=>"U", "dateOfBirth"=>"1983-08-05"}
{"id"=>"2072902-01", "firstName"=>"c", "lastName"=>"d", "email"=>"test@test.com", "gender"=>"U", "dateOfBirth"=>"1955-04-01"}
{"id"=>"1072903-01", "firstName"=>"e", "lastName"=>"f", "email"=>"test@test.com", "gender"=>"M", "dateOfBirth"=>"1987-12-31"}
{"id"=>"2072817-04", "firstName"=>"g", "lastName"=>"h", "email"=>"test@test.com", "gender"=>"U", "dateOfBirth"=>"1985-04-07"}
```

How can i put each id into it's own array? Something like:

```
api_response[:id].each do |x|
  api_response_array << x
end
```

The hashes aren't seperated by commas and I think that is what's throwing me off.

Comment: What is `api_response`? is it a `Hash` or a `String`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
api_response.map { |x| x["id"] }
```

For more documentation, check out [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

EDIT:

The reason the hashes aren't separated by commas is because of how `Kernel#puts` works on an array.  Try `puts [1,2,3]` and see for yourself: each element goes on its own line, without commas.

`api_response` is an array of hashes, so my answer above takes each hash out of the array, and extracts the `"id"` field.

Answer (score 1):

```
resp_str = <<EOS
{"id"=>"5172901-01", "firstName"=>"a", "lastName"=>"b", "email"=>"test@test.com", "gender"=>"U", "dateOfBirth"=>"1983-08-05"}
{"id"=>"2072902-01", "firstName"=>"c", "lastName"=>"d", "email"=>"test@test.com", "gender"=>"U", "dateOfBirth"=>"1955-04-01"}
{"id"=>"1072903-01", "firstName"=>"e", "lastName"=>"f", "email"=>"test@test.com", "gender"=>"M", "dateOfBirth"=>"1987-12-31"}
{"id"=>"2072817-04", "firstName"=>"g", "lastName"=>"h", "email"=>"test@test.com", "gender"=>"U", "dateOfBirth"=>"1985-04-07"}
EOS


resp_array = resp_str.lines.map {|line| eval(line) }
id_array = resp_array.map {|h| h['id']}

puts id_array.inspect
```